# My chatgpt api not working on in router file

Tags: api, next.js, chatbot, next.js13

I  was trying to create custom chatbot and envlocal is ready but my router.js file is not working.

## api/bot/router file code

```
 import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai"
 export  async function POST(request) {
const {messages} = await request.json();
const configuration  = new Configuration({
apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
  });
  const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

  const responce = await openai.createChatCompletion({
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages: [
      {
        role: "system",
        content: "you are a coumtomer suport assistant."
      },
     ...messages,
    ],
  })
  return new Response(JSON.stringify({response:responce.data.choices[0]}));
  // res.status(200).json({ name: "hello ,kii hall aa bhai!" })
}
```

[Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCGKV.png)